# Что такое "исходный код программы"?

Tags: c#, .net

Выдали ТЗ, с самим ТЗ проблем нет. Только Вот один момент, цитирую "надо прислать исходный код и запускаемый файл. Thirdparty не использовать." Подскажите, исходный код это просто все классы, а запускаемый класс это один из них (Program)? Т.е. не присылать всю программу целиком, а только то что на скриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И что такое 3d party? гугл выдает только перевод данной фразы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Зачастую под исходным кодом подразумевают все файлы (и .csproj и .sln в том числе) которые необходимы для успешного билда с настроенным окружением на машине (Есть Visual Studio, установлен MSBuild, допустим), но без файлов .dll, .csproj.Config и т.д.

Т.Е. без файлов которые зависят от твоих текущий настроек студии, и от того как ты сбилдил свой солюшн.

Вот гайд по пользованию .gitignore, все заигноренные в нем файле бессмысленны для билда из исходного кода.
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Answer (score 3):

Запускаемый файл - это исполняемый файл (exe или dll), правда зачем он им - ума не приложу, видно сами не умеют собирать проект (это заказчики не умеющие программировать? тогда ладно. А вот если это контора программистов, куда вас собеседуют - я бы задумался)

По вопросу не совсем понятно, у вас приложение asp.net core (тогда на выходе exe-файл) или у вас сайт asp.net core (тогда у вас набор dll, получаемых при publish проекта).

По поводу компонентов третьих лиц, 3d party. Вам запрещается использовать какие-либо dll, сторонние Nuget-пакеты и т.п. вещи. Возможно, это будет не совсем удобно, но таково у вас ТЗ.

Comment: Это вообще странно (задание кста на трейни). Написано не использовать сторонние библиотеки , но в задании черным по белому "Для реализации взаимодействия с базой данных  использовать Entity Framework." Там 3 задания , одно консольное и два веб. Я все в один солюшн впихнул

Answer (score 1):

Исходный код - весь код, включая все конфигурационные файлы.

Comment: T.e. весь проект целиком архивировать? включая reference properties  и остальные?

Comment: ну по логике - да